# How to put specific order for each container inside a grouping in YANG model?

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

Is there any way to specify the order of containers inside a grouping, instead of letting the system do it randomly?

Example:

```
grouping common-config-def {
    container myContent1 {
      uses myContent1-def;
    }
    container myContent2 {
      uses myContent2-def;
    }
    container myContent3 {
      uses myContent3-def;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you have no control over this, but most implementations will probably follow definition order when consuming the model.

Not sure why such a requirement would be needed, but I'm assuming the issue is model-based instance data encoding. When encoding data, the data nodes may appear in any order with the exception of RPC/action input and output data, list key data nodes and "ordered-by user" list entries.

The specification is quite clear on this, for example, if your grouping were to be used in a container, the following would apply when encoding the data of that container:

> The container's child nodes are encoded as subelements to the
> container element.  If the container defines RPC or action input or
> output parameters, these subelements are encoded in the same order as
> they are defined within the "container" statement.  Otherwise, the
> subelements are encoded in any order.

> [RFC7950, Section 7.5.7.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.5.7)